# How to get the input_variables correctly from Chainlit prompt?

Tags: python, chatbot, py-langchain, llama

Recently, I tried to use Llama 2 model in my PC. I followed the video by "AI Anytime". While, when I provided the input_variables from the Chainlit prompt, I got the error. I searched for some time but no solution. Can you help me?

My code is given below. When I run the code in Anaconda Prompt, I got the error in the Chainlit prompt,
"1 validation error for StuffDocumentsChain
root
document_variable_name context was not found in llm_chain input_variables: ['', 'question'] (type=value_error)"

I did not find the necessity for the input variable, 'context'. While, when I removed it from the code, I could provide the question in the chainlit prompt, but then I got the error message,
"UserSession.set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'"

```
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
import chainlit as cl

DB_FAISS_PATH = "vectorstores/db_faiss" 

# Context: {context}/ 

custom_prompt_template = """Use the following pieces of information to answer the user's question.
If you don't know the answer, please just say that you don't know the answer, don't try to make up
an answer.

Context: {}
Question: {question}

Only returns the helpful answer below and nothing else.
Helpful answer:

"""

def set_custom_prompt():
    """
    Prompt template for QA retrieval for each vector stores
    """
    
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template = custom_prompt_template, input_variables = ['context','question'])
#    prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(custom_prompt_template)
#    prompt.format(question = 'question'])
    
    
    return prompt


def load_llm():
    print("*** Start the load_llm.")
    llm = CTransformers(
        model = "llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",
        model_type = "llama",
        max_new_tokens = 512,
        temperature = 0.5
        )
    print("****** Finish the load_llm")
    return llm

def retrieval_qa_chain(llm, prompt, db):
    qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm = llm,
        chain_type = "stuff",
        retriever = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs = {'k': 2}),
        return_source_documents = True,
        chain_type_kwargs = {'prompt': prompt}
        )
    return qa_chain

def qa_bot():
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name = 'sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2',
                                       model_kwargs = {'device': 'cpu'})
    
    db = FAISS.load_local(DB_FAISS_PATH, embeddings)
    print("*******FAISS.load_local() works well.")
    llm = load_llm()
    print("****** llm step works well.")
    qa_prompt = set_custom_prompt()
    qa = retrieval_qa_chain(llm, qa_prompt, db)
    print("******qa step works well.")
    
    return qa
    
def final_result(query):
    qa_result = qa_bot()
    response = qa_result({'query': query})
    return response
    
# chainlit ####
@cl.on_chat_start
async def start():
    chain = qa_bot()
    msg = cl.Message(content="Starting the bot......")    
    await msg.send()
    msg.content = "Hi, Welcome to the Medical Bot. What is your query?"
    await msg.update()
    cl.user_session.set('chain', chain)
    
@cl.on_message
async def main(message):
    chain = cl.user_session.set("chain")
    cb = cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler(
        stream_final_answer = True, answer_prefix_tokens = ["FINAL", "ANSWER"]
        )
    cb.answer_reached = True
    res = await chain.acall(message, callbacks = [cb])
    answer = res["result"]
    sources = res["source_documents"]
    
    if sources:
        answer += f"\nSources:" + str(sources)
    else:
        answer += f"\nNo Sources Found"
        
    await cl.Message(content = answer).send()
```

I have tried some solution such as removing or changing the position of the 'context' variable. There was always error.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code :

```
chain = cl.user_session.set("chain")
```

to:

```
chain = cl.user_session.get("chain")
```

Because we are already setting the chain variable above, here we have to get that.